# Crear Json con Java Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, rest, tomcat, jersey

Lo que quiero es crear un Json mas estructurado, llenar "lstEquiposxPais" con los equipos por cada Pais, para esto tengo un listado de pais, otro listado de equipos ingluye un idpais para que de alguna manera se asocien por ese idpais, adicionalmente cada uno tiene obtiene los datos de Su DTO correspondiente, sin embargo he tratado de hacerlo pero me manda vacío, soy nueva en esto, así que desearía que me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Alemania",
    "lstEquiposxPais": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Túnez",
    "lstEquiposxPais": [

    ]
  }
]
```

**Los Datos que tengo son estos:**
**Mis DTOcreados son los siguientes**

```
public class PaisConEquipos implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private List<EquipoxPaisDTO> lstEquiposxPais;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public List<EquipoxPaisDTO> getLstEquiposxPais() {
        return lstEquiposxPais;
    }
    public void setLstEquiposxPais(List<EquipoxPaisDTO> lstEquiposxPais) {
        this.lstEquiposxPais = lstEquiposxPais;
    }
    public PaisConEquipos() {   }

    public PaisConEquipos(int id, String nombre) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}

public class EquipoxPaisDTO {
    private int cod_pais, id_equipo;
    private String desc_equipo;


    public EquipoxPaisDTO() {   }

    public EquipoxPaisDTO(int cod_pais, String desc_equipo) {
        super();
        this.cod_pais = cod_pais;
        this.desc_equipo = desc_equipo;

    }

    public int getCod_pais() {
        return cod_pais;
    }

    public int getId_equipo() {
        return id_equipo;
    }


    public void setId_equipo(int id_equipo) {
        this.id_equipo = id_equipo;
    }
    public void setCod_pais(int cod_pais) {
        this.cod_pais = cod_pais;
    }


    public String getDesc_equipo() {
        return desc_equipo;
    }


    public void setDesc_equipo(String desc_equipo) {
        this.desc_equipo = desc_equipo;
    }


}
```

**Mis DAO creados son los siguientes**

```
@Override
    public List<EquipoxPaisDTO> equiposxpais() {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList<EquipoxPaisDTO> lstEquiposxPais = new ArrayList<EquipoxPaisDTO>();
        try {
            con = MySQLConexion.getConexion();
            String sql = "{CALL sp_listado_EquipoxPais ()}";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);


            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                EquipoxPaisDTO l = new EquipoxPaisDTO();
                l.setCod_pais(rs.getInt(1));
                l.setId_equipo(rs.getInt(2));
                l.setDesc_equipo(rs.getString(3));      
                lstEquiposxPais.add(l);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error en la sentencia valida: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null)
                    rs.close();
                if (pst != null)
                    pst.close();
                if (con != null)
                    con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error al cerrar");
            }
        }

        return lstEquiposxPais;
    }


@Override 
    public List<PaisConEquipos> obtenerPaisesConEquipos() {
        ArrayList<PaisConEquipos> lstPaisesConEquipos = new ArrayList<PaisConEquipos>();
        ArrayList<EquipoxPaisDTO> lstEquiposxPais = new ArrayList<EquipoxPaisDTO>();;
        ResultSet rs = null; 
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try {

           con = MySQLConexion.getConexion();
           String sql = "select * from tb_pais";
           pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);  
           rs = pst.executeQuery();
           while (rs.next()){
               PaisConEquipos pa = new PaisConEquipos();
               pa.setId(rs.getInt(1));
               pa.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
               pa.setLstEquiposxPais(lstEquiposxPais);
               lstPaisesConEquipos.add(pa);
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Error en la sentencia " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if(pst!=null) pst.close();
                if(con!=null) con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error al cerrar " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return lstPaisesConEquipos;
    }
```

No sé si debo colocar parametros para que liste segun el codigo del pais
Si hay alguna sugerencia, se los agradeceré